# How to vectorize 3D Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a 3D numpy array like `a = np.zeros((100,100, 20))`. I want to perform an operation over every `x,y` position that involves all the elements over the `z` axis and the result is stored in an array like `b = np.zeros((100,100))` on the same corresponding `x,y` position.

Now i'm doing it using a for loop:

```
d_n = np.array([...]) # a parameter with the same shape as b
for (x,y), v in np.ndenumerate(b):
    C = a[x,y,:]

    ### calculate some_value using C
    minv = sys.maxint
    depth = -1
    C = a[x,y,:]
    for d in range(len(C)):
        e = 2.5 * float(math.pow(d_n[x,y] - d, 2)) + C[d] * 0.05
        if e < minv:
            minv = e
            depth = d

    some_value = depth
    if depth == -1:
        some_value = len(C) - 1
    ###

    b[x,y] = some_value
```

The problem now is that this operation is *much* slower than others done the pythonic way, e.g. `c = b * b` (I actually profiled this function and it's around 2 orders of magnitude slower than others using numpy built in functions and vectorized functions, over a similar number of elements)

**How can I improve the performance of such kind of functions mapping a 3D array to a 2D one?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is usually done in 3D images is to swap the `Z` axis to the first index:

```
>>> a = a.transpose((2,0,1))
>>> a.shape
(20, 100, 100)
```

And now you can easily iterate over the Z axis:

```
>>> for slice in a:
       do something
```

The `slice` here will be each of your `100x100` fractions of your 3D matrix. Additionally, by transpossing allows you to access each of the 2D slices directly by indexing the first axis. For example `a[10]` will give you the 11th 2D `100x100` slice.

Bonus: If you store the data contiguosly, without transposing (or converting to a contiguous array using `a = np.ascontiguousarray(a.transpose((2,0,1)))` the access to you 2D slices will be faster since they are mapped contiguosly in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want to get rid of the explicit `for` loop, but I think whether this is possible depends on what calculation you are doing with C. As a simple example,

```
a = np.zeros((100,100, 20))
a[:,:] = np.linspace(1,20,20)    # example data: 1,2,3,.., 20 as "z" for every "x","y"

b = np.sum(a[:,:]**2, axis=2)
```

will fill the `100` by `100` array `b` with the sum of the squared "z" values of `a`, that is 1+4+9+...+400 = 2870.

Comment: It's a rather complex function i did't want to include to avoid contaminating the example, but basically requires to iterate over C and find some minimum value. The whole thing can be done with numpy standard functions though

Comment: Can you then replace C with a[:,:] as in my example?

Answer (score 0):

If your inner calculation is sufficiently complex, and not amenable to vectorization, then your iteration structure is good, and does not contribute significantly to the calculation time

```
for (x,y), v in np.ndenumerate(b):
    C = a[x,y,:]
    ...
    for d in range(len(C)):
        ... # complex, not vectorizable calc
    ...
    b[x,y] = some_value
```

There doesn't appear to be a special structure in the 1st 2 dimensions, so you could just as well think of it as 2D mapping on to 1D, e.g. mapping a `(N,20)` array onto a `(N,)` array.  That doesn't speed up anything, but may help highlight the essential structure of the problem.

One step is to focus on speeding up that `C` to `some_value` calculation.  There are functions like `cumsum` and `cumprod` that help you do sequential calculations on a vector.  `cython` is also a good tool.

A different approach is to see if you can perform that internal calculation over the `N` values all at once.  In other words, if you must iterate, it is better to do so over the smallest dimension.

In a sense this a non-answer.  But without full knowledge of how you get `some_value` from `C` and `d_n` I don't think we can do more.

---

It looks like `e` can be calculated for all points at once:

```
e = 2.5 * float(math.pow(d_n[x,y] - d, 2)) + C[d] * 0.05

E = 2.5 * (d_n[...,None] - np.arange(a.shape[-1]))**2 + a * 0.05  # (100,100,20)

E.min(axis=-1)  # smallest value along the last dimension
E.argmin(axis=-1)  # index of where that min occurs
```

On first glance it looks like this `E.argmin` is the `b` value that you want (tweaked for some boundary conditions if needed).

I don't have realistic `a` and `d_n` arrays, but with simple test ones, this `E.argmin(-1)` matches your `b`, with a 66x speedup.

Answer (score 0):

> **How can I improve the performance of such kind of functions mapping a 3D array to a 2D one?**

Many functions in Numpy are "reduction" functions<sup>*</sup>, for example `sum`, `any`, `std`, etc. If you supply an `axis` argument other than `None` to such a function it will reduce the dimension of the array over that axis. For your code you can use the `argmin` function, if you first calculate `e` in a vectorized way:

```
d = np.arange(a.shape[2])
e = 2.5 * (d_n[...,None] - d)**2 + a*0.05
b = np.argmin(e, axis=2)
```

The indexing with `[...,None]` is used to engage [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). The values in `e` are floating point values, so it's a bit strange to compare to `sys.maxint` but there you go:

```
I, J = np.indices(b.shape)
b[e[I,J,b] >= sys.maxint] = a.shape[2] - 1
```

<sub>* Strickly speaking a reduction function is of the form `reduce(operator, sequence)` so technically not `std` and `argmin`</sub>