# Any faster way to get the same results?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have two given arrays: x and y. I want to calculate correlation coefficient between two arrays as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

x = np.array([[[1,2,3,4],
               [5,6,7,8]],
              [[11,22,23,24],
               [25,26,27,28]]])


i,j,k = x.shape

y = np.array([[[31,32,33,34],
               [35,36,37,38]],
              [[41,42,43,44],
               [45,46,47,48]]])



xx = np.row_stack(np.dstack(x))
yy = np.row_stack(np.dstack(y))

results = []

for a, b in zip(xx,yy):
    r_sq, p_val = pearsonr(a, b)
    results.append(r_sq)

results = np.array(results).reshape(j,k)

print results

[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

The answer is correct. However, would like to know if there are better and faster ways of doing it using numpy and/or scipy.

Comment: Probably a better question for --> http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The goal is to calculate correlation coefficient between the elements [1,11] of array x and [31,41] of array y, and so on....

Comment: Whether this is really better on `codereview` or not is debatable.  It's a question of `numpy` vectorization, and there have been many such questions on `Stack`.  If the subject line had been 'how do I vectorize this', would you recommend moving it to CR?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624678/ is another recent discussion of `numpy` speedup via vectorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternate way (not necessarily better) is:

```
xx = x.reshape(2,-1).T  # faster, minor issue though
yy = y.reshape(2,-1).T
results = [pearsonr(a,b)[0] for a,b in zip(xx,yy)]
results = np.array(results).reshape(x.shape[1:])
```

Another current thread was discussing the use of list comprehensions to iterate over values of an array(s):  [Confusion about numpy's apply along axis and list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641894)

As discussed there, an alternative is to initialize `results`, and fill in values during the iteration.  That's probably faster for really large cases, but for modest ones, this

```
np.array([... for .. in ...])
```

is reasonable.

The deeper question is whether `pearsonr`, or some alternative, can calculate this correlation for many pairs, rather than just one pair.  That may require studying the internals of `pearsonr`, or other functions in `stats`.

Here's a first cut at vectorizing `stats.pearsonr`:

```
def pearsonr2(a,b):
    # stats.pearsonr adapted for
    # x and y are (N,2) arrays
    n = x.shape[1]
    mx = x.mean(1)
    my = y.mean(1)
    xm, ym = x-mx[:,None], y-my[:,None]
    r_num = np.add.reduce(xm * ym, 1)
    r_den = np.sqrt(stats.ss(xm,1) * stats.ss(ym,1))
    r = r_num / r_den
    r = np.clip(r, -1.0, 1.0)
    return r

print pearsonr2(xx,yy)
```

It matches your case, though these test values don't really exercise the function.  I just took the `pearsonr` code, added the `axis=1` parameter in most of the lines, and made sure everything ran.  The `prob` step could be included with some boolean masking.

(I can add the `stats.pearsonr` code to my answer if needed).

---

This version will take any dimension `a`,`b` (as long as they are the same), and do your `pearsonr` calc along the designated axis.  No reshaping needed.

```
def pearsonr_flex(a,b, axis=1):
    # stats.pearsonr adapted for
    # x and y are (N,2) arrays
    n = x.shape[axis]
    mx = x.mean(axis, keepdims=True)
    my = y.mean(axis, keepdims=True)
    xm, ym = x-mx, y-my
    r_num = np.add.reduce(xm * ym, axis)
    r_den = np.sqrt(stats.ss(xm, axis) * stats.ss(ym, axis))
    r = r_num / r_den
    r = np.clip(r, -1.0, 1.0)
    return r

pearsonr_flex(xx, yy, 1)
preasonr_flex(x, y, 0)
```

Comment: How can I modify your vectorizing function when the shape of x and y are (3,3,5) and (3,3,5) respecively.

Comment: I've suggested a couple of way of generalizing the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Can't the def pearsonr2 be integrated into def pearsonr_m so that a single function could be applied for any shape, i.e., (2,2,4 in the first case) or (3,3,5 in another case) considering the pearson is applied to the last dimension.

Comment: I've rewritten my function to work with any shape and do the correlation on any axis.

Comment: Than you so much, it's great.